# Does ValueTuple is a bad choice if there are too many "fields" due to its value type nature?

Tags: c#, .net, tuples, valuetuple

Since I decided to diversify myself with Rust and Go I became overly concerned about copying / reference / moving etc.

And recently I really wondered if `ValueTuple` also suffer from the typical caveat of `struct` that is that its size should not be greater than 16 bytes to avoid a performance when copying the value type here and there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1082341/4636721

So if say we have a value tuple `(decimal, decimal, decimal, decimal)` that means we are better off using classic `Tuple<decimal, decimal, decimal, decimal>` class to pass around that tuple?

[EDIT]

An example of use case: let's say the method below would be call a lot

```
public (decimal, decimal, decimal, decimal) GetSuperImportantTuple(int input)
{
    var aParameter = GetAParameter(input);

    // Copy when getting that tuple
    var tuple = GetA4DecimalsValueTuple();

    // Copy into that function
    var anotherParameter = GetAnotherParameter(tuple);

    // Copy when returning the value
    return TransformValueTuple(tuple, anotherParameter);
}
```

Comment: Not a dupe, but closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44652082/4137916 . Pay particular attention to the last point. There are programs where being concerned about copying is justified, but there are many, many more where it's not.

Comment: Need more of a usecase to say wether it's good in that given situation.

Comment: @fstam sure will update my post with an example

Comment: Sure.  There was originally a lot of FUD over whether to make Tuple<> a class or a struct.  They went for class, that's convenient right now.

Answer (score 0):

Like always, it depends. Value types and Reference types [differ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/value-types-and-reference-types). This difference can be relevant for the performance. However, you can also decide to just [pass something by reference argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref). If you want to know what really runs faster for the situation and the way you want to use it, [test it with the stopwatch](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/). Performance, is typically something to measure, not something to ask.

Comment: +1 The cost of copying value types increases with size, but the cost of passing them by `ref` does not.  Since the cost of creating immutable object also increases with size, the best approach is often to use mutable value types, passed by `ref`.