# Using tuples in C#, (A, B, C) vs Tuple<string, string, string>

Tags: c#, tuples, valuetuple

I've created a method:

```
public static Tuple<string, string, string> SplitStr(string req)
{
    //...
    return (A, B, C)
}
```

it complaint that `"CSOOZQ: Cannot implicitly convert type '(strinq _keyword, strinq _filterCondition, strinq _filterCateqory)' to 'System.Tuple<strinq, strinq, string)‘"`

But if code:

```
public static (string, string, string) SplitStr(string req)
{
    //...
    return (A, B, C)
}
```

The error goes away. From the error, it looks like the bracket form of tuple and the one `Tuple<>` are different.

1. Is it safe to use the bracket form ?
2. What's the difference, why are there 2 types of Tuple ?  Should I use the `Tuple<>` in my case ?  How do I return the Tuple ?

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of [When to use: Tuple vs Class in C# 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44650636/when-to-use-tuple-vs-class-in-c-sharp-7-0)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between System.ValueTuple and System.Tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41084411/whats-the-difference-between-system-valuetuple-and-system-tuple)

Comment: "I looked at the source for both Tuple and ValueTuple. The difference is that Tuple is a class and ValueTuple is a struct that implements IEquatable.

That means that Tuple == Tuple will return false if they are not the same instance, but ValueTuple == ValueTuple will return true if they are of the same type and Equals returns true for each of the values they contain." [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41084594/4108016)

Comment: I sorry.  Before, I didn't know about these terms System.ValueTuple and System.Tuple.  I tired to search  () and Tuple<>, didn't get anything helpful.  That's why I posted the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type [`Tuple<T1,T2,T3>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple-3) is different than the type [`ValueTuple<T1,T2,T3>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple-3). In general using [value-tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples) is preferable to reference-type tuples, because:

1. They don't add pressure to the garbage collector.
2. There is language support for naming the members of a value-tuple.

My suggestion is to declare the `SplitStr` like this:

```
public static (string First, string Middle, string Last) SplitStr(string request)
{
    // ...
    return (a, b, c)
}
```

You can then consume it like this:

```
var parts = SplitStr(request);
// Use parts.First, parts.Middle and parts.Last
```

...or using tuple deconstruction, which is also possible with reference-type tuples.

```
var (first, middle, last) = SplitStr(request);
```